# access the value of attribute (as a variable)

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to transform my xml file:

```
<root>
    <group id="F_123" >
        <term id="F_123_d" >
            <word>blabla</word>
            <instruction>blabla</instruction>
        </term>
        <term id="F_123">
            <word>blabla</word>
            <instruction>blabla</instruction>
            <numbers>
                <number code="01" >1</number>
                <number code="02" >2</number>
                <number code="03" >3</number>
                <number code="04" >4</number>
                <number code="05" >5</number>
            </numbers>
        </term>
        <term id="F_124">
            <word>blabla</word>
            <numbers>
                <number code="01" >1</number>
                <number code="02" >2</number>
                <number code="03" >3</number>
                <number code="04" >4</number>
                <number code="05" >5</number>
            </numbers>
        </term>
        <term id="F_125">
            <word>blabla</word>
            <numbers>
                <number code="01" >1</number>
                <number code="02" >2</number>
                <number code="03" >3</number>
                <number code="04" >4</number>
                <number code="05" >5</number>
            </numbers>
        </term>
        <routing id="F_123_1">
            <condition>
                <operator type="or">
                    <operator type="or">
                        <operator type="equal">
                            <variable name="F_D01a3DE1"/>
                            <constant>DK</constant>
                        </operator>
                        <operator type="equal">
                            <variable name="F_D01a3DE1"/>
                            <constant>RF</constant>
                        </operator>
                    </operator>
                    <operator type="equal">
                        <variable name="F_D01a3DE1"/>
                        <constant>1</constant>
                    </operator>
                </operator>
            </condition>
            <then>
                <goto group="A_24"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <routing>
                    <condition>
                        <operator type="or">
                            <operator type="or">
                                <operator type="equal">
                                    <variable name="B_D01a3DE1"/>
                                    <constant>5</constant>
                                </operator>
                                <operator type="equal">
                                    <variable name="B_D01a3DE1"/>
                                    <constant>10</constant>
                                </operator>
                            </operator>
                            <operator type="equal">
                                <variable name="B_D01a3DE1"/>
                                <constant>7</constant>
                            </operator>
                        </operator>
                    </condition>
                    <then>
                        <goto group="A_25"/>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <routing>
                            <condition>
                                <operator type="or">
                                    <operator type="equal">
                                        <variable name="B_D01a3DE1"/>
                                        <constant>6</constant>
                                    </operator>
                                    <operator type="equal">
                                        <variable name="B_D01a3DE1"/>
                                        <constant>11</constant>
                                    </operator>
                                </operator>
                            </condition>
                            <then>
                                <goto group="A_26"/>
                            </then>
                            <else>
                                <goto group="A_27"/>
                            </else>
                        </routing>
                    </else>
                </routing>
            </else>
        </routing>
    </group>
    <group id="A_25" >
        <term id="A_25" >
            <word>blabla</word>
            <instruction>blabla</instruction>
        </term>
        <term id="A_26">
            <word>blabla</word>
            <instruction>blabla</instruction>
            <numbers>
                <number code="01" >1</number>
                <number code="02" >2</number>
            </numbers>
        </term>
    </group>
</root>
```

I want to access the value of @group/term/@id and make one element per each term in  `<group id="A_25">`. Is it possible?

Comment: A representative sample would have been enough, though it is not clear what the output you want. Can you post a sample of the output you need?

Comment: If that expression was meant to be XPath, the it's wrong, @ means attributes in XPath, the correct expression would be `group/term/@id`.

Comment: You haven't defined exactly what output must be produced and how the output is related to the provided XML document. Please, define these, don't force eceryone to try to guess what you really want. !!!

Comment: I've edited your input sample to be proper XML input.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what exactly do you want, so a guess follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="group/term/@id">
    <id>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your example (I had to add a root element to it, so that it's valid), it produces:

```
<root>
  <id>F_123_d</id>
  <id>F_123</id>
  <id>F_124</id>
  <id>F_125</id>
  <id>A_25</id>
  <id>A_26</id>
</root>
```

Comment: There is no need for a pattern to begin with `//` operator.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to access the value of
>   @group/term/@id and make one element
>   per each term in `<group id="A_25">`. Is
>   it possible?

This XPath expression select what I think you want:

```
/root/group[@id='A_25']/term/@id
```

Also, this stylesheet process what I think you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="group[@id='A_25']/term">
        <element id="{@id}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<element id="A_25" />
<element id="A_26" />
```